# What energy do even degree splines minimize?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, reference-request, interpolation, spline

For odd degree splines, with degree $k$ I know they minimize an energy:

$$E[u] = \int_{a}^{b} \left\|\frac{d^{(k+1)/2}u}{dx^{(k+1)/2}}(x)\right\|^2 \, dx, \, u(x_i) = f(x_i), \, \frac{d^l u}{dx^l}(c) = 0, \, c\in\{a,b\},$$

for sufficiently many derivatives $l$ on the boundary. Is there an analogue of the above for even degree splines. Surely those minimize something? However when I tried to derive this, the skew-adjoint operator $\frac{d^{k+1}}{dx^{k+1}}$ got in the way.

Is there a discussion of this fact in the literature?

Comment: Don’t know the answer, but generally a good place to start looking is de Boor’s book  “A Practical Guide to Splines”.

Comment: @bubba Thank you, I will look into de Boor's book. I am still not sure but after some derivations I figured that there probably isn't an energy since the odd order differential operators are skew-adjoint. I have read Duchon and Meinguet on the topic but they consider only even order differential operators (i.e. odd degree splines).